# Why is array.slice returning different values on Safari than in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have several divs. On click, I would like to set a separate img element's src to be the background image of the div the user just clicked.

To do this, I run this function when the user clicks one of the divs:

```
document.getElementById('image--roof').src = 
shingleButtons[i].style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);
```

This works great in Chrome, but in Safari the .slice() function returns a different value.
In Chrome, clicking `shingleButtons[i]` sets the src of `#image--roof` to `http://example.com/example.jpg`. In Safari it sets it to `ttp://example.com/example.jp`.

Here's a Codepen that demonstrates the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEjzyg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The CodePen in question has a lot of extraneous stuff in it, and it's not at all clear what we're meant to do or see there.

Comment: Did you at least try logging  `shingleButtons[i].style.backgroundImage` on both browsers ?

Comment: Your code relies on browsers reporting the style value (in this case, apparently it's the URL you're after) in a perfectly consistent way. That's fragile. You'd be better off adding your own `data-` attribute containing the URL so that you can be 100% sure you're in control of the values.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is the value of `backgroundImage` on Safari vs. Chrome? I guarantee you `slice` behaves the same on both, the source string is just different.

Comment: @DenysSéguret well right; in this case it's that particular style value, which is apparently the URL desired.

Comment: My debugging had consisted of changing the slice parameters. I (stupidly, now that I look back on it) didn't log the string. It looks like Chrome returns the URL with quotation marks around it, while Safari doesn't. 
I will figure out how to add a `data-` attribute and use that.

Comment: @Andrew Write this as an answer. This might help other users.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome returns the URL with quotation marks around it, while Safari doesn't. I will figure out how to add a data- attribute and use that.